# "__new__" create an infinite recursive loop

Tags: python-3.x

I learned `__new__` from [**new** and **init** | Spyhce blog](https://spyhce.com/blog/understanding-new-and-init) such an example:

```
class A(object):  

    def __new__(cls):
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls) #I think here is an infinite recursive
```

the code could be rewritten as

```
class A(object):  

    def __new__(A):
        return object.__new__(A)
```

It's algorithms:

1, define A inherit from object
2, override method `__new__` by `def __new__(A)` but parameter A is not implemented until it is called
3, object.**new**(A), recursively call A

This is definitely  an infinite recursively iterating.

How the infinite loop stop?

Comment: Not able to reproduce. This is not going into infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, it doe not ,but why? @VineethSai

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't cause an infinite recursion because you aren't calling the `__new__` method of the `A()` class. You are calling the `__new__()` method of it's `super` class which is still untouched and behaves as default.

So It's simple now, as the method belongs to its superclass *not* your `A` class, so this
`__new__` requires class reference to be passed the first argument and it will create the instance for you. And that's what this `super(A, cls).__new__(cls)` line does.

Comment: not convincing, cls has not definded, how could it be passed in if with your thinking.

Comment: cls is just a parameter. cls could be anything. So in your code `cls` becomes your `A` and that reference `A` gets passed into the `__new__()` method.

Comment: it could be anything as a varialbe, it itself in very very very nature is AAAA

Comment: I think you need a refresher on how overriding/variable passing and Python's inheritance. It's quite straightforward what's happening here :)

Comment: No, I am thinking the case in C and C++ of its details implemetation.

Answer (score 0):

As is clearly said in the comments of the other answer, you are mistaking the variable A local to the staticmethod `__new__` for the class name A, which exists in a more global scope. By convention, this is something like cls for `__new__`, and your choice of typing A is confusing you. I think this is an example of massive overthinking of one of the first-learned concepts in Python.

That A in the inner call to `object.__new__` is not the same variable as the A you chose for the class name. Scope is relevant no matter if programming magic methods or simple scripts.

You erroneously changed this between examples.... leading to your confusion. cls (as you wrote correct in first version) is essentially a placeholder for the class definition, which once and here only is sent to a different method so without a **call** back, like if `object.__new__(x)` called `x.__new__`, how could there be recursion?